# Need clarification on this sentence

Tags: early-modern-english

I came across this sentence:

> You have done that you should be sorry for.

Is this grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was grammatical for Shakespeare. And it is only by choice that it is not something we say today.

> 1 You have done that you should be sorry for.

What is this? Well, it is a sentence with the relative pronoun dropped. If we replace the relative pronoun, we get either:

> 2 You have done that that you should be sorry for.

(The first *that* is a demonstrative pronoun: 'You have done *that.*' The second *that* is a relative pronoun.)

or

> 3 You have done that which you should be sorry for.

Are 2 & 3 grammatical today? Yes, although we really don't like two *thats* coming in a row, so we might prefer Sentence 3.

Perhaps Shakespeare didn't like two *thats* in a row, either. All he did was drop the relative pronoun. It is something we still do *in some constructions,* but it sounds a bit weird in this particular sentence construction. So it is not really grammatical for us, but that is only because we say it is not. Which is all 'grammatical' means: if it is something we say, it's grammatical.

Note you can switch the word order and come up with all the following:

> 4 You should be sorry for that which you have done.
>
> 5 You should be sorry for that that you have done.

Grammatical? Yes. Sounds a bit weird? Probably.

> 6 You should be sorry for what you have done.

Grammatical? Yes.

> 7 You should be sorry for that you have done.

Grammatical? Well, it's beginning to sound grammatical... Some native speakers might say yes.

Another example from *Julius Caesar*:

> 8 Now follows that you know, young Fortinbras,...

Again, Shakespeare has simply dropped the relative pronoun *that*:

> 9 Now follows that that you know, young Fortinbras,...

This one sounds okay to me, but again it becomes clearer if we use the relative pronoun *which* instead.

> 10 Now follows that which you know, young Fortinbras,...

Here are a lot more examples of [Shakespeare dropping the relative pronoun](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.03.0080%3Asection%3D4%3Asubsection%3D7%3Aparagraph%3D244), in many places (that) we don't do so today.